# Can you please helo with this Error: DeprecationWarning for 'punycode' Module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, module, version, punycode

I am very new to Node, so sorry if my question is not a fit for this forum. (I appreciate if you give me tips for other Node or Javascript/Typsecript forums).

I am getting this error message when running my program in Typescript:

r/node - Can you please helo with this Error: DeprecationWarning for 'punycode' Module?
I googled that it could help to downgrade Node version. But I am getting this error with both v21.4.0. and v20.9.0 (which I tried according to advice).

Could you give me a hint on this error please? What are other solutions?

(I don't use punycode explicitly in my code).

I tried to run my program and was expecting it to work. The error appeared immediately after I run it. I got no other errors.